# NSURLConnection Object Ignoring It's Implemented Methods

Tags: ios, delegates, nsurlconnection

My question relates to the code in my single-threaded app that updates the devices' local database data via a NSURLConnection to a web service.

My  NSURLConnection initialization is not going into any of it's implemented methods and it has me puzzled.
Inside my AppDelegate.m -> applicationDidFinishLaunching method, I am creating a NSURLConnection object:

```
//AppDelegate.m
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{

   // ... Building request URL here ...

   NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", URI,urlEncodedParamStr]
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]];
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

   responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

   if(connection !=nil)
      [connection release];

}
```

Execution should now proceed to any of the following appropriate NSURLConnection methods 
that I implemented in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{[responseData setLength:0];}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {[responseData appendData:data];}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{//my implementation}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {//my implementation}
```

But instead, execution continues, with the line directly after the init of NSURLConnection *connection, not executing any of the NSURLConnection implemented methods. I have confirmed that the request is not nil and put breakpoints in the implemented NSURLConnection methods - They are not being called.

[image: Debugging session screenshot]

What's going on?

Thanks as always!

Comment: You need to post some more code, we can't even see if you're starting the request from what you've posted here.

Comment: Sure. Code has been added. That's all of the code in applicationDidFinishLaunching, sans the URL creation string stuff, which is creating a valid URL. Thanks for looking at this, guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call

```
[connection start];
```

before the remote call will actually be started.

**And even then, the next line of code will execute.**  It's an asynchronous call and is executed in a background thread.  The response is received later and your `connection...` method will be called then (which can be up to the timeout (30 seconds) time later).

Comment: expand on "had no effect" . . . confirm (with debugger or NSLog) that request is non-nil, put breakpoints (or NSLog) in all `connection` methods, execute code for long enough for failure (default 30 seconds)

Comment: Yeah, I already stepped through this in the debugger and confirmed that the request is not nil and put break points in all implemented methods - I attached a screen shot that shows debugger and how the connection object methods are being ignored, jumping right to responseData variable assignment. Thanks!

Comment: Read the answer again. It's an asynchronous call.

Comment: there's not a `[connection start]` in your code - despite you thinking it "didn't work", **IT IS REQUIRED**.

Comment: Sorry, it was there, didn't work so I pulled it out. Actually it isn't required according to Apple unless using initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:

Causes the connection to begin loading data, if it has not already.
- (void)start
Discussion
Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection with the initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and provide NO for the startImmediately parameter. If you don’t schedule the connection in a run loop or an operation queue before calling this method, the connection is scheduled in the current run loop in the default mode.

Comment: you're correct there, sorry (my head was elsewhere).  Though it may be scheduled in the current run loop, it is /not/ completed there, and IS asynchronous.  Only the callbacks will give you anything useful, or an indication of success/failure.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Still having issues but I appreciate all of the guidance! Thanks.